# android eclipse Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v7.widet.RecyclerView>

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I got crazy about this problem.Even now I don't know what is the cause. I have already import the android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar. Moreover, I extract the classes.dex from my final apk file , and covert it to jar. Then I open the jar with jd-gui, I saw the android.support.v7.RecyclerView in the class list. I don't why the dvm cannot load the RecyclerView class. Anyone can help me?

**Here is my Logcat:**

03-23 16:25:50.859: I/art(22281): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

03-23 16:25:50.877: I/art(22281): Debugger is no longer active

03-23 16:25:50.973: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.973: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.974: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.974: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.974: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.974: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.975: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.975: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.976: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.987: I/art(22281): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281): Process: com.adxmi.android.flow, PID: 22281

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adxmi.android.flow/com.adxmi.android.demo.ContentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.facebook.ads.MediaView

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)

03-23 16:25:50.989: E/AndroidRuntime(22281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

Comment: Same here in 2017!

Comment: `Clean` then `Rebuild` worked for me...